# testing framework selection

Tags: testing, frameworks, automated-tests, robotframework

Greetings,

I am looking for a testing framework.

Currently we have a home grown Perl script that loops through the input files, calling an AWK script which in turn connects to a server, then collects the output and compares it to a saved output file. This is done on Linux. Currently there are just over 100 tests. We are planning a major refactoring and I want to revamp the test system and tests first.

In thinking about the framework requirements, I want a system that can logically collect tests into test suites, automatically detect test files, and can create test prerequisites / dependencies. I have been looking at QMTest and Google's Robot Framework. I would rather extend an existing system than do heavy lifting of the very small Perl script that now runs the tests. Perl is not a requirement. In fact I would rather use Python, not Perl, but that is a personal opinion.

I have been looking through
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks for possible frameworks to use.

Thanks

Comment: Curious, what did you end up doing?

Comment: Just wanted to point out some high level general purpose frameworks that haven't been mentioned: http://staf.sourceforge.net, https://github.com/Top-Q/jsystem, http://redwoodhq.com

Answer (score 4):

You said you've looked at "Google's Robot Framework" so I'm not sure if you're talking about the same thing or not, but there is a framework called the [robot framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) that is not owned by google. It allows you to write your scripts using keywords, and custom keywords can be implemented with Python and Java, and also with any .NET language. Note: you can't directly mix .NET and java keywords since .NET keywords need to run with IronPython and java keywords need Jython. However, there is a way to write keywords in any language and access them via a remote API.

It has some very nice features such as tagging and XML output, and comes with a variety of tools and libraries. I highly recommend it.

http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/

Comment: Thought I'd provide an update. Since this post, Robot Framework now has sample remote API (server) implementations in Java, .NET, and even Perl, for which you can extend and use with your own keyword libraries. Saves time from building server from scratch. And using such remote API allows mixing keywords from different languages within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Go for fast and simple.

For example I really like the tests in the Go language https://go.googlecode.com/hg/test/ and their https://go.googlecode.com/hg/test/fixedbugs/ and https://go.googlecode.com/hg/test/bugs/ directories.

Shell is a lot faster than Python and much easier to port.

Answer (score -1):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good fit for the question asked. Although the Selenium WebDriver API (JSONWireProtocol) could perhaps be useful to adapt for a general purpose test framework.